# What might explain the loss of -l- from Latin to Old French?

Tags: phonology, latin, old-french

[feeble (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=feeble&searchmode=none) [:] 
    late 12c., "lacking strength or vigor" (physical, moral, or intellectual), from Old French feble "weak, feeble" (12c., Modern French faible), **dissimilated** from Latin *flebilis* "lamentable," literally "that is to be wept over," from *flere* "weep, cry, shed tears, lament," from PIE **bhle-* "to howl" (see [bleat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bleat&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)). **The first -*l*- was lost in Old French.** The noun meaning "feeble person" is recorded from mid-14c.

Is the loss of the first -l- part of a larger phenomenon?

I am unsure whether dissimulation explains the loss of the first -l- here, because nothing in the Latin *flebilis* [/ˈfleː.bi.lis/, [ˈfɫeː.bɪ.lɪs]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flebilis), seems to sound like the first syllable in Old French *feble*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is dissimilation, or more specifically loss by dissimilation. There are two [l] sounds in the word originally, and one of them dissimilates to zero, i.e. is lost. This is a common type of sound change.